# Ошибка при использовании mysqli

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Решил в кой-то веки поправить ошибки в проекте на php, включил вывод всех ошибок. Помимо прочего, php ругается на использование mysql, ну ок, попробуем рекомендованную mysqli.

Простейший запрос SELECT lid FROM logs роняет MySQL, отчего тот перезапускается. В таблице порядка 700К записей. В процессе выдается ошибка: Warning: Empty row packet body in /home/www/test/2.php on line 11 Warning: mysqli_query(): (00000/0): in /home/www/test/2.php on line 11

Чем это лечить? Возможно, mysqli пытается полностью получить все данные, и MySQL не тянет эту нагрузку?

Comment: Тип таблицы MyISAM? Если да, то поменяйте на InnoDB.

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780521/strange-mysql-error-empty-row-packet-body-when-using-mysql-fetch-object-php-5) ответ @andreyqin расписан более подробно.

Comment: Тип InnoDB.